# Evaluating the integral of a vector field

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, line-integrals

I am trying to find a loop integral of a vector field $F$ on a closed curve but I have no idea how to show it since the polynomials are not specified.

Given that polynomials $P(x)$, $Q(y)$ and $R(z)$ and $$F(x,y,z) = f(|r|)(P(x),Q(y),R(z))$$
where $|r| = \sqrt{x^2 +y^2+ z^2}$ and $f: \mathbb{R}_{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is any smooth function.
The aim is to find a loop integral of $F$ evaluated on any simple closed curve $\gamma$ on the sphere $S_{R}^{2}$ and $R>0$ be arbitrary.

Comment: Your "proof" does not seem valid to me. In the thing you say you are proving, it says $f$ is any smooth function, but in the "proof" you seem to consider only the case $f(|r|)=1/|r|$. I don't think the claim is true in general.

Comment: $F$ is not conservative in general

Comment: Thank you, then if F is not conservative what trick can I use to integrate this vector field on  a simple closed curve that is on a $S_{R}^{2}$  for R >0

Comment: @David K.   Doesn't the $f = \frac{1}{|r|}$ hold because of the statement that I had forgotten to state that $f : \mathbb{R}_{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ since function excludes the possibilities of $|r| = 0$

Comment: Did you forget anything else? That the domain is $\mathbb R_+$ means that $f(|r|)=1/|r|$ is a _possible_ choice for $f$. I don't see how it implies that $f$ _must_ be $1/|r|$. There are plenty of other smooth functions from $\mathbb R_+$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: If you're restricted to a curve on $S^2_R$ for a fixed $R$ then it seems to me that $f$ becomes irrelevant; $f(|r|)$ will be constant over the curve. This would be very important information. I suggest you edit the question again and this time make sure there is nothing that you forget to mention.

Comment: I edited it , I hope it makes more sense now

Answer (score 0):

Let $\gamma$ be a closed curve on the sphere $S^2_{R_0}$ for some arbitrary 
$R_0 > 0$ (I write $R_0$ to distinguish this radius from the polynomial named $R$).
Let $k = f(R_0).$ Note that $k$ is a simple number that can never change unless we change the value of $R_0$ (and hence have a different sphere and presumably also a different curve).

Then for any point $(x,y,z)$ on the curve $\gamma,$

$$ F(x,y,z) = k(P(x), Q(y), R(z)).$$

Hence the integral of $F(x,y,z)$ over $\gamma$ is the same as the integral of
$k(P(x), Q(y), R(z)).$

But
$$ k(P(x), Q(y), R(z)) = k(P(x), 0, 0) + k(0, Q(y), 0) + k(0, 0, R(z)). $$

Integrate the three functions on the right-hand side separately over $\gamma,$
then add the results.